# The new operator return value in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, operator-keyword

In C#, a new operator can be used to init an object of specific type (class). For example, consider we have a Person class, the following code create an object instance from Person class:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Leopold", 6);
```

My question: what does the `new Person("Leopold",6)` actually return?
Does it return :

1. The reference to the Person object

OR

2. The object itself?

Comment: If `Person` is a class, it returns a reference. The value of the `person1` variable is a reference, too. There's no concept of something returning "the object itself" (for a reference type) in C#.

Comment: When a constructor for a class is called, the instance of the object is allocated onto the heap, and you are returned a reference to that. Now for the other things you have tagged: 1) like in Java, dotnet doesn't want you to worry about pointers, but we *do* have [pointer types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code) primarily for interop with unmanaged code and/or unsafe code 2) passing-by-reference uses the [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword, the linked docs are very clear on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that if `Person` is a `class` then `new Persion()` returns a *reference* to the object.

It is good that you are thinking about reference vs. value semantics. Note that it is not the `new` keyword to define the semantics, but what data structure is being initialized.

When the .NET Framework started there was a clear line between the two, but in recent years things aren't so clear anymore with new additions to the language.

I am going to attempt a list below placing different language constructs in the value vs. reference semantics and mark this answer as a wiki for others to add/edit

| [Value Semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) | [Reference Semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types) |
| --- | --- |
| user structures `struct Foo { }` | user classes `class Foo { }` |
| primitive integers `int`, `long`, `byte` | interfaces `interface IFoo { }` |
| other primitives `char`, `bool` | `string`, literals `"abc"` |
| primitive numbers `float`, `double` | record types `record Foo(int Age) { }` |
| named constants `enum` |  |
| literal tuples `(1,2,3)`, `ValueTuple<>` | tuples `Tuple<>` |
| `Span<T>`, `Memory<T>` |  |
| nullable value types `int?`, `long?` etc | nullable reference types `string?` |
| user ref structures `ref struct { }` |  |

<sub>Not that there is nothing stopping you from using the `new` keyword with primitive types, such as `x = new double();`</sub>

Answer (score -1):

For your case, it returns the reference which points to object memory location created in heap. Providing below example for better understanding.

```
`Box b1; //Reference variable, can not create memory //b1 is called a reference variable (not object). As of now, b1 is null  
Box b2 = new Box();// object b2 of class BOX is instantiated and create memory on Heap. now b2 points box object  
Box b3 = new Box();  // object b3 (new object created with new memory)
b3.length = 10;  
b3.width = 20;  
  
b1 = b3; //an object is assigned to a reference variable 

//now both b1 and b3 both points to same memory location. if any one updated then another one automatically updated.`
```

Hope it helps!

you can also refer the below link explaining the same in detail:
[https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3434/object-creation-and-difference-between-object-and-reference-variable-in-c-sharp.aspx#:~:text=Object%20is%20an%20instance%20of%20a%20class.%20Class,b1%20is%20called%20a%20reference%20variable%20%28not%20object%29](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3434/object-creation-and-difference-between-object-and-reference-variable-in-c-sharp.aspx#:%7E:text=Object%20is%20an%20instance%20of%20a%20class.%20Class,b1%20is%20called%20a%20reference%20variable%20%28not%20object%29)